# Convert a Web service from GET to POST

Tags: ios, web-services, post, joomla, get

I have created a web service to make a communication between an iOS application and a Joomla web site, and I used the GET method to communicate between the mobile application and the web service and also between the web service and the controller (PHP file that does the work and return the data) , but I didn't find how to convert the implementation to POST method here is the actual system :

**ws.php** : it's the web service (simple example )

```
<?php 
      $id = $_GET['id'] ; // get the data from the URL

// here i make testes

// then I redirect to the controller of the Joomla component that receive 
// the call of the request the URL is actually the attribute "action" of 
// an existing HTML Form that implement the login system, I added a 
// parameter called web service to help me to modify the controller 
// to make the difference between a normal call and a web service call

header("Location: index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=login&ws=1&id=1");
?>
```

**Controller.php** : the receiver of the web service call and the web call (from browser)

```
<?php 
// code added by me, in the existent controller of the component
// it was waiting for a form submitting, so I got to convert my data to POST here

if (isset($_GET['ws'])) // it's a web service call 
{
   $_POST['id'] = $_GET['id'] ; 

   // do the task ... 

   if ($correctLogin) // just an example 
     echo "1"
   else 
     echo '0';
}
?>
```

I didn't put the real implementation, and it's just a simple example of the system, but it's the same

**Call from the mobile**

```
 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://localhost/ws.php?id=1"];

 NSData *dataUrl= [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

 NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:dataUrl 
                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if(![str isEqualToString:@"0"])
    NSLog(@"connected");
else
    NSLog(@"not connected");
```

so I don't want to use the GET method, I just want to receive my data from the mobile using POST and also send the data to the controller using POST also, what is the best solution ?

Comment: Can't you just use `$_REQUEST` as it handles both `$_POST` and `$_GET`?

Comment: I don't want to use `$_GET` from the begin, I just want to send data from the mobile using `$_POST` and also from the web service to the controller. In the actual system I used the redirection to send data from the two PHP files, but I want to change that and use `$_POST` to send the data between the two PHP files and between the mobile application and the web service

Answer (score 1):

If you want your app to send data using POST method, then I'm this code. I hope it will help.

It takes the data to be sent in dictionary object.
Ecodes the data to be sent as POST
and then returns the response (if you want the results in string format you can use [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dresponse encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]; when returning data)

```
-(NSData*) getData:(NSDictionary *) postDataDic{

    NSData *dresponse = [[NSData alloc] init];

    NSURL *nurl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSDictionary *postDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:postDataDic];
    NSData *postData = [self encodeDictionary:postDict];

    // Create the request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:nurl];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; // define the method type
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", postData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        // Peform the request
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *error = nil;

        dresponse = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request  
                                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                                 error:&error];

    return dresponse;
}
```

This method prepares the Dictionary data for POST

```
- (NSData*)encodeDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary {
    NSMutableArray *parts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *key in dictionary) {
        NSString *encodedValue = [[dictionary objectForKey:key] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *encodedKey = [key stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
        NSString *part = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@=%@", encodedKey, encodedValue];
        [parts addObject:part];
    }
    NSString *encodedDictionary = [parts componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
    return [encodedDictionary dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is useful, but only in the iOS implementation side, I still need to change the web service from using GET to POST.

Comment: You are redirecting to other url, so you cannot send post data via url, you can use curl to get the results, but one other solution can be to dump your POST data in a session variable like ($_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;) and then in your controller check if $_SESSION['post'] has data or not, if no data act normal, else $_POST = $_SESSION['post']; and unset($_SESSION['post']);

Comment: Thank you again for your comment, as I know session variable is a client side since it store the data inside a cookie if I am not wrong, and my request will be from the mobile not from a browser ! correct me if I am wrong ? but the stuff of cURL I think that it can works, basically I need to submit/send the data of the action attribute of an existent html form

Comment: Session is stored at server side, not the client, but if you want to maintain the same session for the user, store the user session id (e.g. in db table) and use this to load the particular session for each user. But since your are concern about POST, you can use session to pass POST data and then discard the data from session. And how is your component returning data, is it working with GET + redirection ?